# Insert multiple email(Unique Key) rows in your database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to populate a table that has the next structure:

```
USERS_TABLE
ID_USR (Primary_Key, AUTO_INCREMENT)
USERNAME (Not Null)
EMAIL (Not Null, Unique Key)
Password(Not Null)
Nacionality (Not Null)
Work (Null)
```

And I want to do it with a php script. It's not a problem for me to create the script but I have some doubts with the email's field. I don't want real names or emails, just data and the posibility to introduce over 10-100 rows.

So with the ID_USR I don't have problems because it's an auto increment value, no problems with the not null's or null's fields.

Now think about the email, as you see it is a unique key so I thought about putting two random numerical values​​, one before and one after @ and then the extension.

Example:

```
<?php 
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
$a = rand();
$b = rand(); // array("gmail", "facebook", "hotmail", "outlook", "yahoo".....);
$extension = array(".com", ".es", ".net", ".org"); // ....
$c = rand(0,3);
$email = $a."@".$b."".$extension[$c];
echo "$email";
}
?>
```

It returns to me:

```
2095518299@699790428.com 
254450939@1623171070.org 
1142680888@2074501004.org 
1940419404@1779299580.es 
726585010@1262850036.net 
578544275@145818927.net 
2067281904@1894405902.org 
275443932@1915863743.es 
734209458@1269004984.com 
1035465063@1828742272.net
```

As you can see this can work but my question is if there is a smarter/efficient way.

I think this may be constructive so I hope your answers. See you.

Comment: Why "populate" the table with nonsense data, rather than simply waiting until there is some real data to use?

Comment: I need "virtual" users to keep working on my project, I have other tables that have this one as a FK so I need to populate this one. There are other reasons but I don't care about them.

Comment: Like how many are you thinking off ???

Answer (score 2):

Aha, the test data problem!

If I were you I'd use a domain name you control for the domain part of the email addresses.  That is,

```
  726585010@emailtest.yoyodyne.com 
  578544275@emailtest.yoyodyne.com 
  2067281904@emailtest.yoyodyne.com
```

(if you happen to work for Yoyodyne.) This will prevent randomly generated email addresses from escaping into the wild if you should make an error and try to send to everybody.

Then, use a longer random number for the number so you don't get many accidental collisions. You will probably will get some.

Finally, after you populate the table, before you use it, go back and change the email column so it incorporates the id number.

```
 UPDATE USERS_TABLE SET EMAIL = CONCAT(ID_USR,'@emailtest.yoyodyne.com')
```

That way your tests will be readily traceable back to particular user rows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that is what I was looking for. Some experience of someone who also works in the guild.

Comment: also, possibly generate the number from the timestamp for guaranteed uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry don't know what's "from the timestamp"

Comment: You can return the current unix timestamp (the number of seconds elapsed since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) by calling time() This long string of numbers, if appended with a random number, nearly guarantees uniqueness, provided you don't have many calls to the script in a second

Comment: Careful! You only get one new Unix timestamp a second.  If you're bulk loading 10K rows you might not want to restrict your throughput to one  row a second; you'll take almost three hours to do the load.

Comment: @OllieJones What I actually said was, `This long string of numbers, if appended with a random number, nearly guarantees uniqueness`